# Filter a table by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, filter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function filterResults() {

    var trTag = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < trTag.length; i++) {
        if (trTag[i].OuterHTML.includes(filterTXT.Value)) {
            trTag.Style.Display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Firefox tells me: `trTag[i].OuterHTML is undefined`. I assume this is because `OuterHTML` does not exist? If so, what do I use instead?

Comment: Add HTML structure here.

Comment: Use `outerHTML` instead of `OuterHTML`. the property names are case sensitive.

Comment: Gah, I gotta get used to case sensitivity.

Comment: You should also change `Style`, `Display` to `style`, `display` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language.

> JavaScript is case sensitive. It is common to start the name of a constructor with a capitalised letter, and the name of a function or variable with a lower-case letter ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax)).

You might want to make these changes

- `outerHTML` not `OuterHTML` ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML))
- `style` not `Style` ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style))
- `display` not `Display` ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference))
- `value` not `Value` ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/value))

in your script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function filterResults() {

    var trTag = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < trTag.length; i++) {
        if (trTag[i].outerHTML.includes(filterTXT.value)) {
            trTag.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```